# Rotated Excel cell text not printing rotated

Tags: c#, .net, excel, gembox-spreadsheet

I am using GemBox.Spreadsheet to populate an Excel template with data. One of the cells has been set to rotate its content 90 degrees. When the file is saved to disk, the text is rotated correctly, but when printing the ExcelFile object directly to a printer, the cell content is not rotated. This causes the text to display one letter below another, rather than being "turned on its side".

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

The newer versions of GemBox.Spreadsheet support [`CellStyle.Rotate`](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/docs/GemBox.Spreadsheet.CellStyle.html#GemBox_Spreadsheet_CellStyle_Rotation) when printing or exporting to PDF, XPS and image formats.

**ORIGINAL:**

The current version of GemBox.Spreadsheet (version 3.9) does not support CellStyle's Rotation property when printing or exporting to PDF, XPS and image formats, see [this help page](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/Supported_File_Formats.htm#PdfSupportLevel).

There is a feature request for this and you can vote for it in order to increase its priority, see [this feedback page](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/support-center/feedback/view/19-support-rotated-characters-when-printing).